# Incorrect size of a textview frame (self.textview.frame.size.height)

Tags: ios, uitextview, frame

I want to change the height of a textview depending on its content. I created the method to resize its view. The first time I call this view controller it resize properly (height = 253) but not the other times (height = 296).

I tried resizing it from viewDidAppear, viewWillAppear and viewDidLoad. The first time viewDidAppear and viewDidLoad are called. Second and following times all methods (viewDidAppear, viewWillAppear and viewDidLoad) are called. I don't know the reason and I don't know why this weird behavior, any clue?

```
-(void) setHeight
{
    NSLog(@"Set height");
    CGRect frame = descriptionTextView.frame;
    frame.size.height = descriptionTextView.contentSize.height;
    descriptionTextView.frame = frame;
    NSLog(@"height: %f", descriptionTextView.frame.size.height);

    if([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568) //iPhone 4inch
    {
        totalHeight = 380+frame.size.height;
        [self.mainScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,totalHeight)];
    }
    else{
        totalHeight = 250+frame.size.height;
        [self.mainScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,totalHeight)];
    }    
}
```

I use autolayout in my project but not for this view since I dont know how to properly resize a textview inside a scrollview (which also includes 2 more views with labels, images and buttons) based on the textview content with autolayout. Is it better to use autolayout than this function? Perhaps you can help me with the constraints...

Comment: where do you exactly call that method? what value do you expect? I also see that you are changing scroll size not the textView accordingly

Comment: Do you have auto-layout turned on? It might be causing the issues you are talking about.

Comment: I tried calling it from viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear and viewDidLoad. Same behavior, first time resize properly, second and following times not. This viewcontroller (view) is placed inside a containerview since I have a custom tab bar.

Comment: Where are you actually setting the height of the UITextView

Answer (score 0):

You are changing only the scroll size according to your calculation but you are missing to change the size of text view itself. After setting scroll view content size update the size of the text view and all should be fine (contentSize and frame). This may look like:

```
[descriptionTextView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(descriptionTextView.frame),totalHeight)];
CGRect frame = descriptionTextView.frame;
frame.size.height = totalHeight;
[descriptionTextView setFrame:frame];
```

By the way: in the if-statement you can only calculate totalHeight and set it afterwards.

Additionally you do not need this line:

```
frame.size.height = descriptionTextView.contentSize.height;
```

Comment: I changed it (descriptionTextView.frame = frame). However I also tried with your code and I get the same behavior: first time works, following times not.

Comment: Fine, but you want to change it twice on entering view?

Comment: I only want to change it once. The content comes from a JSON file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CGSize constraintSize;
constraintSize.height = MAXFLOAT;
constraintSize.width = yourTextView.frame.size.width;
NSDictionary *attributesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                      [UIFont fontWithName:@"yourFontName" size:yourFontSize], NSFontAttributeName,
                                      nil];

CGRect frame = [yourTextView.text boundingRectWithSize:constraintSize
                                  options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                               attributes:attributesDictionary
                                  context:nil];
// Use this frame for your textview
```